# A/c gauge temp doing weird. Sky coupe gt 350

Tags: ford, ac, cooling-system, mustang

I have a gt350 coupe and I know when I am parked with the a/c on it will overheat in an hour, so I need to turn a/c off. But this time while driving the temperature gauge started going down, not overheating. The car is driving fine and produces no sounds out of the ordinary. Then last time engine light came on... Do I need to service my car?

Comment: Have you checked the coolant level? Only do that when it is cold...

Comment: Hei Mike, you know i filled the coolant (because it went down) one day and Right now its a little above the max level but the coolant then never get down but im going to scan it. I will get back to you.

Comment: Maybe need to flush the old coolant put new one? ‍♀️

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no leaks. A pressure tester can help you do this. Or you can keep running it and monitor usage by noticing if the level drops after multiple uses. But with engine temps varying like they are I would do a pressure test and confirm it isn't a head gasket problem or air getting into the system. If it passes a pressure test, the most likely cause is a faulty thermostat. If it fails the pressure test and there is no external leak, then a compression test is needed to find a head gasket leak. But hopefully you won't have to go that far.

Comment: Well guys i went scanning it. It came that “Oxygen sensor” was it but mechanic reset it and drive it didnt came back and it seems its working. Also i think its not working good because it rained here in Aruba❗️& i was roading and maybe it get wet. So let keep praying it can keep working 